# Connecting to Zap Proxy Docker Image, "Max retries exceeded with url: Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, zap, zapproxy

I'm trying to use [zap proxy via Docker](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker) 
Pulled it down with:

```
 docker pull owasp/zap2docker-stable
```

Ran it with the command described in "Accessing the API from outside of the Docker container" section:

```
 docker run -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8090 -host 0.0.0.0
```

But I don't seem to be able to be able to connect to it. When I run `docker inspect <CONTAINER ID> | grep IPAddress` I'm getting 172.17.0.2 (EDIT: I can a scan to run and it took me changing ZAP_SERVER_PROXY from `172.17.0.2:8090` to `0.0.0.0:8090` on Mac so editing that into code example below). So the start of my script looks like:

```
import os
import time
from pprint import pprint
from zapv2 import ZAPv2

BASE_URL = os.getenv('BASE_URL', 'https://example.appspot.com/')
ZAP_SERVER_PROXY = os.getenv('ZAP_SERVER_PROXY', '0.0.0.0:8090')
API_KEY = ''

zap = ZAPv2(
    # apikey=API_KEY,
    proxies={
        'http': "http://%s" % ZAP_SERVER_PROXY,
        'https': "https://%s" % ZAP_SERVER_PROXY
    }
)
```

Just trying to run it through terminal using python right now and keep getting connection refused errors. Also I've tried it with the `API_KEY` parts commented out as well, does anyone know where you find that don't see it in the documentation.

Note: I'm on macos but running `docker-machine ip default` doesn't do anything, so not sure how to get  at bottom of linked page and new to docker. Modeled the test after their own [example](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-python/blob/master/src/examples/basic-spider-scan.py). Running in a `virtualenv -p python3 env` not sure if that is effecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, you will need to disable ip filtering - see [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQapikey) for details on how to do that, basically just use the following:

```
docker run -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8090 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.disablekey=true -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true
```

Be careful as it will allow connections from any ip to Zaproxy, which is fine while running it in isolated docker container.

Comment: Thank you for linking to documentation. I'm on Mac OSX sierra, pip installed python-owasp-zap-v2.4==0.0.11, and running latest version of owasp/zap2docker-stable (2.6.0). I think this issue (https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/1686) may have been closed incorrectly because it doesn't work with ```-config api.disablekey=true``` but will work with ```-config api.key=9203935709``` argument if I uncomment ```apikey=API_KEY,``` in my script and use the matching api key. Will you please change answer to  suggest trying that if api.disablekey=true doesn't work.

Comment: I am now reading carefuly your question, I am suspecting this might  be docker issue, and not zaproxy issue. I personally running Zaproxy using the command  above and it is working - connecting succesfully. Did you check that you can open tcp connection to zapproxy? try `nc -vz 0.0.0.0 8090`. Also, you can use docker for mac - and then you don't  need the docker-machine anymore...

Comment: ```nc -vz 0.0.0.0 8090``` succeeds and I am running the image using docker for mac.  If I run ```docker run -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8090 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.disablekey=true api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true``` and then trigger script above with the API keys commented out I get this error:

Comment: You forgot a ```-config``` flag in front of ```api.addrs.addr.name=.*```. If you run:
```docker run -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -port 8090 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.disablekey=true -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true```
it works. Please edit

Comment: Thanks, sorry - I was just looking in my answer  wonder why it is not working. Editted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you've commented out the API key parameter in your script,try invoking zap daemon with  `-config api.disablekey=true`.

> docker run -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon
>   -port 8090 -host 0.0.0.0 -config api.disablekey=true